# Determine UNIX version without using uname command?

Tags: unix

Is it possible to which flavor of UNIX a machine is running (AIX, HP-UX, etc.) without using uname command? If so, what other method/command is used to determine this?

Comment: What do you mean by OS name? The version? The patch level? That it's just AIX in general?

Comment: Thats ok.I am asking like how to find it is AIX or not?is there any oither command like uname is used to find the System name?

Answer (score 2):

uname would be the almost universal command for unix/linux based systems. I wonder why you want to avoid to use it. 
    So, if you discard "uname" we would need to concern with Unix specific comands, such as "lsb_release" from most of recent Linux distributions or cat /etc/*-release. prtconf would also help to identify in some Unix.
Some Unix systems, such as AIX, come with this info in the "/etc/motd" too, if not changed. 
    Again, trying to avoid to use uname would put you only in situation of uncertainty and limitations.

EDIT:
You can also do "cat /proc/version" which will work in many *nix*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

But I think this only would be of use on a Linux system.